# how to make llvm project compile faster?

Tags: xcode, llvm

I'm a llvm new learner

after `cmake -S llvm -B build -G Xcode -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="clang;libcxx;libcxxabi"`

I got a llvm project, compiling the project is so slow

How to make it compile faster?

`Ninja`  is an option.

[image: 777]

from the build folder, I see `libLLVMWindowsManifest.a`

[image: 99999]

i don't need windows platform version.

I just need X86 version

###### How to make the complier do less job, by avoid compiling unrelated CPU architecture?

Comment: From my experience, disabling backends does not win you a lot of time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**-DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD="X86"** is the flag you're looking for. But this alone won't speed up the build time significantly.

Play with **CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE** (**-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release/Debug/RelWithDebInfo/MinSizeRel**) and see which suits you better. The default for **CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE** is **Debug**, and it's very slow.

If you want to debug builds, **-DLLVM_OPTIMIZED_TABLEGEN=ON** will improve your build time.

And finally, in my experience Ninja builds are slightly faster.

Comment: It's not true that the `Debug` build is very slow. In fact it's one of the faster builds as it doesn't include the optimization that e.g., `Release` builds include.